# opencart how to filter products by attributes

Tags: filter, opencart, product

I'm creating online electronic shop, in this i'm using lot of attributes. I'm trying to filter products using those attributes. I really don't have any idea  to where to start this?

Please share me your idea to solve this.

Comment: No one having any suggestion for this?

Comment: There's some extensions on the opencart site for this, i'd try there: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_search=filter%20attributes

Comment: Thanks for your reply Stann0rz... I wish to create my own rather using someone's modules.. Are you having any idea to do this?

Comment: @Vin_fugen did you find out? if yes can you please help me?

Comment: No cristina Ursu.. I purchased a $10 extension from http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=10098  it's working like a charm. My kind advice is to buy this without wasting your time like what i did

Comment: That link is dead ... is the link wrong or has the extension been removed already?

Comment: Indeed the link isn't working. Try this one http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=15974 Works perfectly well, frequently updated, and there is good support.

Comment: I think flexi product filter extension can solve your problem. Please take a look https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=35570&filter_member=TemplateMaza